# Formato Fecha en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Mi problema es que quiero agregar una columna  de fecha en este formato 
2016-08-13
exactamente en este Orden lo logre con este:

```
 DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y-%m-%d')
```

pero ahora necesito el mismo formato pero sumando 30 dias  algo asi pero no tengo idea

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y-%m-%d')+30
```

el detalle esta en que cuando hago el simbolo +30 me sale esto
0000-00-00 
¿como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza Interval con la cantidad de días:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY,'%y-%m-%d')
```

o puedes usar la función DATE_ADD():

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), '%y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Bro lo intente pero me dio este error [SQL]INSERT INTO `internat_almacen`.`sr_escalas` (`id`, `nombre`, `nombre_esp`, `nombre_eng`, `nombre_bra`, `fecha_inicio`, `fecha_fin`, `orden`) VALUES (1, 'Escala  1', 'Escala  1', 'Escala  1', 'Escala  1', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y-%m-%d'),DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAYS,'%y-%m-%d'), '0');
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAYS,'%y-%m-%d'), '0')' at line 1

Comment: es DAY, no DAYS ;)

Answer (score 1):

Esto me funcionó en una oportunidad para agregar días a una fecha:

```
$fecha = date('Y-m-j');<br>
$nuevafecha = strtotime ( '+10 day' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) ;  
$nuevafecha = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $nuevafecha );<br>
echo $nuevafecha;
```